# Split a Table into 2 or more Tables based on Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I have a Table called "MIVTable" which has the following records,

```
    MIVID      Quantity         Value
   ------     ----------       --------
      14           10             3000
      14           20             3500
      14           15             2000
      15           20             3000
      15           50             7500
      16           25             2000
```

Here, I need to store the above Table into two tables such as "HeaderTbl" and "DetailTbl" based on the MIVID as follows:

HeaderTbl:

```
   HID      MIVID       TotalQuantity    TotalValue
  -----    -------      -------------    -----------
    1         14               45           8500 
    2         15               70          10500
    3         16               25           2000
```

Here HID is the Primary Key with Identity Column.

DetailTbl:

```
  HID        MIVID        Quantity        Value
 -----      -------     ------------     -------
   1           14             10           3000
   1           14             20           3500
   1           14             15           2000
   2           15             20           3000
   2           15             50           7500
   3           16             25           2000
```

Suppose, if the MIVTable contains 4 different MIVID means, then 4 row should be created based on the MIVID on the HeaderTbl. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert records in `HeaderTbl` from `MIVTable` use this: (`HID` should be auto increment)

```
INSERT INTO HeaderTbl
    ([MIVID], [TotalQuantity], [TotalValue])
SELECT MIVID, SUM(Quantity), SUM(Value) FROM MIVTable GROUP BY MIVID;
```

To insert records in `DetailTbl` from `HeaderTbl` and `MIVTable` use this:

```
INSERT INTO DetailTbl
([HID], [MIVID], [Quantity], [Value])
    SELECT H.HID, M.* 
      FROM HeaderTbl H 
INNER JOIN MIVTable M
        ON H.MIVID = M.MIVID;
```

## [Look at this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44a31/1)

Here you need to use [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/) statement to insert data from one table to another. You can also use `JOIN` in such statement as I did it for `DetailTbl`.

Answer (score 1):

You would generate the HeaderTbl using [RANK() SQL Server function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), as follows:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIVID) as HID, MIVID, TotalQuantity, TotalValue
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    MIVID, 
    SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity, 
    SUM(Value) as TotalValue 
FROM MIVTable GROUP BY MIVID
) AS A
```

and the Detail table using the [ROW_NUMBER() SQL Server function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIVID) AS HID, 
    MIVID, 
    Quantity, 
    Value 
FROM MIVTable
```